PromQL filter by date in label
There is a metric that looks like this:
{__name__="app_common_opts", instance="my-servise",
release_date="2024.04.03 12:27:35"} 1

I need to fetch all records from the last day, meaning release_date > '2024.04.03 12:27:35' - 1 day. Please note that the filtering is specifically based on the release_date field and not the date the metric was collected.
ChatGPT provided me with this option, but it doesn't work.
app_common_opts{release_date=~"2024-04-03.*"} and time() - timestamp(release_date) <= 1d

Prometheus couldn't understand either time or timestamp. I tried other options as well, but Prometheus refuses to parse such constructs.

You can't. Labels in Prometheus only support comparison as strings and regex matching. No arithmetics of any kind.

General advice for this problem: don't store values in labels. They are designed not for this. If you want to store date, and be able to later calculate something based on it: create a proper metric with timestamp of release as value.

@markalex Thank you. I can't change the save system as you suggest. How can I create a filter that matches '2024-04-03.*' by inserting the current date here?

Creating regex to match all dates in a span for 24 hours from arbitrary point is a non trivial task. But to check only for dates, ignoring hours you could use selector app_common_opts{release_date=~"2024\.04\.03.*"}

Thank you. How can I substitute the current date instead of "2024.04.03."?

You can't......
